# Nodejs: How to set the file name for eval?

Tags: node.js, eval, stack-trace

**Background:** I developed a small module system for node.js that asynchronously loads all required code from a separate source server and compiles it with `eval(code)`.  My problem is that for all run-time errors in such "eval-ed" code, the stack trace shows `<anonymous>` as the file name --- I cannot distinguish which code piece is referred to.

**My question:** Is there a way to set the file-name for eval so that the stack trace shows some program-defined string instead of `<anonymous>`?

**My current (imperfect) solution:** As of now, I write the code to a file and load it with `require(file)`. This will sow the file name --- but it is a complicated workaround.

**Note:** Normally, the run-time errors do not show up at the compilation of the eval call, but later, when the compiled code is used.  Thus, try/catch around the eval does not help to identify which code piece failed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use eval (ever). For your purpose you can use [`vm` module](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) ([vm.runInThisContext](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinthiscontext_code_filename) or else).  You can pass file name as an argument. `require` internally does the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Comment: "Don't use eval (ever)." Don't distribute this idea. Eval could be used in different cases, but it make developer think about security and so.

Comment: It's my opinion, but I mean it. If you need eval-ish thing, use `new Function`

Comment: I hate the idea that ONLY emphasizing your "principles" but do NOT ANSWER the original question which may not fit your principle but can be useful in some specific real case that you never thought of, and put that as an ANSWER.

Answer (score 4):

Eventually, this new feature of the V8 engine will make its way to Node.js:

[Issue 2948:    Support //# sourceURL= and //# sourceMappingURL= in v8's parser](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2948)

This method works for Browsers currently.